# Has Gmail withdrawn webbug protection?

Tags: gmail

Anyone else find that Gmail's webbug protection has silently disappeared?

Despite that Google previously announced

> "Instead of serving images directly from their original external host 
>   servers, Gmail will now serve all images through Google’s own secure proxy 
>   servers."

(below), Gmail is now showing me MailChimp message images served direct from 
MailChimp's list-manage.com and mandrillapp.com, with tracking info:

```
/track/click?u=[snip]&id=[snip]
```

---

https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html

> "Have you ever wondered why Gmail asks you before showing images in emails? 
>   We did this to protect you from unknown senders who might try to use images 
>   to compromise the security of your computer or mobile device.
>   But thanks to new improvements in how Gmail handles images, you’ll soon see 
>   all images displayed in your messages automatically across desktop, iOS and 
>   Android. Instead of serving images directly from their original external 
>   host servers, Gmail will now serve all images through Google’s own secure 
>   proxy servers."

Comment: Not that I've heard, and I follow Google pretty regularly. I'd expect that if this were true there would be a large uproar. Is it possible that instead MailChimp has devised a way to get around Gmail's webbug protection?